# FB.XFBML.parse Uncaught [object Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

Why this doesn't work ?

```
$('.fb-like-button').each (function(){
    if ($(this).html() == "" || !$(this).html() || $(this).html() == "undefined")
        {
            $(this).html('<fb:like href="'+$(this).attr("data-url")+'" layout="button_count" send="false" show_faces="false" width="100" action="like" font="verdana" colorscheme="light" />');
            FB.XFBML.parse($(this));
            $(this).attr("class", "done");
        }
});
```

Error: Uncaught [object Object]

Comment: $(this).attr("data-url") can you alert this & check url ?

Comment: Yes, I did: console.log($(this).attr("data-url")) and url is correct. Error is here: FB.XFBML.parse($(this));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. I don't know why but this works:

```
FB.XFBML.parse($(this).get(0));
```

Comment: The reason: parse() is waiting for DOM Element Object as argument, not jQuery Object.